# Media Centre on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

I am trying to install media centre on windows 8. I downloaded a key and installed it on my laptop with no problems.

When I try to install on it my desktop it informs me that the key checks out but then hits me with an error saying 'Something went wrong', 'Close this wizard and try again'.

After numerous reboots it always throws the same error.

Anybody have any idea why?

**UPDATE:**

```
2012-10-30 19:18:08, Error                 WAU    DoTransmogrify failed due to error 0x80070246.
2012-10-30 19:18:08, Error                 WAU    UpgradeSKU failed. Exiting.
2012-10-30 19:18:08, Error                 WAU    The worker process exited unexpectedly
2012-10-30 19:18:08, Error                 WAU    Something went wrong
2012-10-30 19:18:08, Error                 WAU    Close this wizard and try again.
```

**UPDATE - CBS.log**

```
2012-10-31 16:44:41, Info                  CBS    Exec: Processing complete.  Session: 30258995_853840040, Package: Microsoft-Windows-ProfessionalWMCEdition~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.9200.16384 [HRESULT = 0x80070246 - ERROR_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER]
2012-10-31 16:44:41, Error                 CBS    Failed to perform operation.  [HRESULT = 0x80070246 - ERROR_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER]
2012-10-31 16:44:41, Info                  CBS    Session: 30258995_853840040 finalized. Reboot required: yes [HRESULT = 0x80070246 - ERROR_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER]
2012-10-31 16:44:41, Info                  CBS    Failed to FinalizeEx using worker session [HRESULT = 0x80070246]
```

Comment: is it the same key?

Comment: @Louis - No, different key

Comment: If you paste this into Explorer a log file will open in a text editor: `%localappdata%\microsoft\windows\Windows Anytime Upgrade\Upgrade.log`. Can you post the part of that was written during the error?

Comment: Have you tried Right Click "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: @vian-esterhuizen - no. this option is not available

Comment: @Louis - i have posted this.

Comment: @John Okay, thanks. That error is from an illegal character somewhere. I would try to repair the offending file by running `sfc /scannow` in the Command Prompt. Also, more information about the error might be in `%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`. I wonder if you can find the same time period, or errors around there, and share that with us?

Comment: @Louis - i ran the add feature again just now and took the last entry in CBS log.

Comment: @Louis - ran `sfc /scannow` it did correct errors the feature still fails to install and I get the same error in the CBS log.

Comment: @John Sorry, I can't find much going on those logs. The [System Update Readiness Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-the-System-Update-Readiness-Tool) is supposed to fix that error, but there doesn't seem to be a Windows 8 version. I know you said your PC is up to date, but can you make sure you have [this update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34879)?

Comment: @John Also, take a look at [Method 2 of this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833#method2), it shows how to find out if `sfc` couldn't repair something.

Comment: @louis - thanks for all the help. Nothing seems to help at the moment. I will wait a few weeks and see if any resolutions emerge. I can't be the only one with this issue. J.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure everything is updated in Windows Update
2. If you have a file called "ehome" in "c:\windows", delete/move it.
3. If you have moved your "Users" folder to another disk (e.g. D:\Users) with a junction point, put it back first.

Comment: everything is up to date, there is no ehome file in C:\windows and I have not moved the Users folder anywhere. Also, out of curiosity, what is a junction point?

Comment: A junction point is like an alias for one directory to another location. Apparently the installer doesn't like it. I had exactly the same issue and #2 was problem. Do you have an error in the file \Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Anytime Upgrade\Upgrade.log ?

Comment: yes. it is in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Junction Point the solution for the Media Center Pack installation's problem is simple (DO NOT COPY again the Users directory back to system partition but) follow these simple steps:

- Launch REGEDIT (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type Regedit)
- Searching "ProfileList" in Keys and Values, it goes to
  "`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`"
- Change `%SystemDrive%` with the unit that contains your Users folder in Default, ProfilesDirectory and Public (LEAVE `ProgramData` AS IS)
  for example:  `%SystemDrive%\Users` --> `D:\Users`
- Start again Media Center Pack installation, it will work!
- After machine restarting, you can put `%SystemDrive%` variable again inside the `ProfileList` Key
  Hoping to help for this problem.
  Best Regards!